# Why is the component only created twice?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a separate module with a routing module imported into it, in which the routes look like:

```
    const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        children: [
            {
                path: 'orders',
                component: MainComponent,
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        component: OrdersComponent,
                        pathMatch: 'full',
                    },
                    {
                        path: ':orderNumber',
                        component: OrdersComponent,
                    },
                ],
            }
        ],
    }];
```

**this.location: [Location](https://angular.io/api/common/Location), this.router: [Router](https://angular.io/api/router/Router)** - Angular services

Reproduction steps:

1. Use **this.router.navigateByUrl('/orders');** - we see the **OrdersComponent** component (to make sure the component is initialized, I added a message in the console to the component's constructor).
2. Use **this.router.navigateByUrl('/orders/12345');** - we see the same **OrdersComponent** component (The message appeared in the console again, i.e. the component **OrdersComponent** has been initialized again).
3. Use **this.location.replaceState('/orders');**
4. Use **this.router.navigateByUrl('/orders/98765');** - we don't see messages in the console => component constructor not called.

**My question is:** Why, when repeating steps 3 and 4 (The order numbers can be any), the component is created only for steps 1 and 2 and never again? But if replace **this.location.replaceState('/orders');** from Step3 with **this.router.navigateByUrl('/orders');**, then the constructor will be called on each repetition of steps 3 and 4?

Comment: Maybe this can help: 

https://medium.com/@juliapassynkova/angular-2-component-reuse-strategy-9f3ddfab23f5

Comment: @DieterRehbein 
Thanks, it really helped. I was confused that the transition in step 4 was called with Router and the value of this.router.url changed, but as a result of using location -  this.router.url changed from '/ order/ 1' to '/order/ 2'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular is reusing the component and is only initializing the component when navigating to a route, which you have not been at before. When navigating to a route you have already been at, the component is reused.

If you have to run a specific function either look for another place to put your function call than In the constructor. Maybe take a look at angular lifecycle https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Or maybe make a subscription to ActivatedRoute and run your function every time the Route changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Indeed, location.replaceState() did not trigger the change router.url, as a result of which router.url there was always like '/orders/:orderNumber'